# Is it possible to export a function from rust dll which takes a reference as a parameter

Tags: rust

I'm new to learning rust and I saw that rust uses generic lifetimes to validate references at compile time which is very nice. I didn't dig much around building a dll or shared library in rust but from what I saw a function can be exported from dll (like in c++). But if I want to export a function that takes a reference as a parameter or returns a reference other than static references, how will this work ? the dll and the app are not in the same project so the compiler can't check lifetimes in this case so this is simply not possible like exporting templated functions in c++ is not possible without instantiation but I don't know how instantiate a generic lifetime function in rust.

Why ask this question ? rust is aimed to be a system programming language and shared libraries are mandatory in any system so how a system built in rust will provide its api in pure rust without going through c ?

In c++ this is possible like in c :

```
struct some_type_c
{
  int i;
  float f;
  void* p;
};

// vary between windows and unix likes
#define EXPORT some_platform_export

EXPORT void use_some_type_c(some_type_c* s) { ++s->i; }

struct some_type_cpp
{
  int i;
  float f;
  void* p;
  
  // may be implemented in a cpp file
  EXPORT void use() { ++i; }
};
```

Comment: I'm a novice too but I'd guess that would have to be in an unsafe block, since rust can't validate the memory use / pointer lifetime at compile time because it knows nothing about the caller.  So it's something to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rust has no stable ABI, exported functions need to go through the C ABI and deal with raw pointers along the way.

When going through C, it's common practice to create more ergonomic functions that wrap the underlying [*unsafe* FFI (foreign function interface) calls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html) and have the right lifetime annotations in order to represent the relationship between different references.

Crates that dynamically load system libraries are often composed of two crates, one with a `-sys` suffix, containing the FFI bindings, and the more ergonomic version (e.g. `openssl` depends on `openssl-sys`, containing generated C-compatible types, using `bindgen`).

When exporting functions, the references lifetimes are lost when converting them to raw pointers.

However it's worth noting that all rust crates are statically linked at compile time, and lifetime checks are enforced across crate boundaries.